how I can read the log4net.config
I have added the new config node under log4net.config file
like this
<appender name="file" type="CustomLogger.RollingFileByMaxAgeAppender">
    <file value="main.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
    <maximumFileSize value="25MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <myCustomConfig value="100"/>   -> this is the new config node I have added in log4net.config 
  </appender>

I need to read it from library
using log4net.Appender;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace CustomLogger
{
    public class RollingFileByMaxAgeAppender : RollingFileAppender
    {
        public RollingFileByMaxAgeAppender()
            : base()
        {
        }

        protected override void AdjustFileBeforeAppend()
        {
            base.AdjustFileBeforeAppend();
           ///Need to read here value of "myCustomConfig"
        }
    }
}


The first thing you would need to do is add a property to RollingFileByMaxAgeAppender so the config builder can assign myCustomConfig to it

thanks @stuartd, It was so simple .. some how I forgot that RollingFileByMaxAgeAppender getting loaded from config itself ..
